# GNU R ANOVA with aov(): Multiple variables as factors vs. one variable with multiple factors

Tags: r, statistics, anova

Currently, I am evaluating a questionary with a repeated measure design. I would like to do an analysis of variance. However, I came across an issue fitting the model.
Why does it make a difference whether I model factors either as
Multiple variables (each representing a single factor), or
Within one variable (where each factor is represented by a value of the variable)?

In order to illustrate my question, I chose the following example (adapted from [this tuorial](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/repeated.html)):

```
### Data with repeated measures
groceries <- data.frame(
  c("lettuce","potatoes","milk","eggs","bread","cereal",
    "ground.beef","tomato.soup","laundry.detergent","aspirin"),
  c(1.17,1.77,1.49,0.65,1.58,3.13,2.09,0.62,5.89,4.46),
  c(1.78,1.98,1.69,0.99,1.70,3.15,1.88,0.65,5.99,4.84),
  c(1.29,1.99,1.79,0.69,1.89,2.99,2.09,0.65,5.99,4.99),
  c(1.29,1.99,1.59,1.09,1.89,3.09,2.49,0.69,6.99,5.15))
colnames(groceries) <- c("subject","storeA","storeB","storeC","storeD")

### Rearranging data for ANOVA (r); 'store' is the variable with 4 factors
groceries <- cbind(stack(groceries[,2:5]), rep(groceries$subject,4))
colnames(groceries) <- c("price", "store", "subject")

### Adding 4 columns for each factor -> thus, 4 boolean variables  
factorLookup <- as.character(unique(groceries$store))
groceries <- cbind(groceries, 
                    sapply(1 : length(factorLookup), 
                           function(x) groceries$store ==  factorLookup[x]))
names(groceries)[4:7] <- factorLookup

### ANOVA using variable 'store' as factor
aov.1var <- aov(price ~ store + Error(subject/store), data=groceries)
summary(aov.1var)

### ANOVA using 4 factor variables
aov.4fact <- aov(price ~ storeA * storeB * storeC * storeD 
               + Error(subject/(storeA * storeB * storeC * storeD)), data=groceries)
summary(aov.4fact)
```

These are the results, which are clearly not the same for both approaches. In addition, they come with a warning for the multiple variable approach:

```
> ### ANOVA using variable 'store' as factor
> aov.1var <- aov(price ~ store + Error(subject/store), data=groceries)
> summary(aov.1var)

Error: subject
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  9  115.2    12.8               

Error: subject:store
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
store      3 0.5859 0.19529   4.344 0.0127 *
Residuals 27 1.2137 0.04495                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> ### ANOVA using 4 factor variables
> aov.4fact <- aov(price ~ storeA * storeB * storeC * storeD 
+                + Error(subject/(storeA * storeB * storeC * storeD)), data=groceries)
Warning message:
In aov(price ~ storeA * storeB * storeC * storeD + Error(subject/(storeA *  :
  Error() Modell ist singulär
> summary(aov.4fact)

Error: subject
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  9  115.2    12.8               

Error: subject:storeA
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)   
storeA     1 0.3763  0.3763   16.02 0.0031 **
Residuals  9 0.2115  0.0235                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subject:storeB
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
storeB     1 0.0290 0.02904    0.54  0.481
Residuals  9 0.4842 0.05380               

Error: subject:storeC
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
storeC     1 0.1805 0.18050   3.135   0.11
Residuals  9 0.5181 0.05757
```

Which keeps me puzzled: Both approaches would lead to the same results using a linear mixed model (e.g. lme {nlme}). Why does not the same apply for an ANOVA?

Maybe something about my general understanding of ANOVA is wrong. Why isn't there any F-value output for each factor using the single variable approach?!

Any help appreciated a lot!

Comment: That warnings about the singular matrix should warn you. You are over-specifying your model with the separate factors. You probably want `aov.4fact <- aov(price ~ storeB + storeC + storeD  + Error(subject/(storeB + storeC + storeD)), data=groceries)` but if you don't understand why, that's a statistics problem, not a programming problem. You would be better off seeing statistical help on [stats.se] as such matters are off-topic here.

Comment: You're trying to fit a quite complex mixed model. Are you absolutely sure you can have interactions in the random part of the model?

Comment: @MrFlick: `aov.4fact <- aov(price ~ storeA + storeB + storeC + storeD + Error(subject/(storeA + storeB + storeC + storeD)), data=groceries)` leads to the same result as `aov.4fact <- aov(price ~ storeA * storeB * storeC * storeD + Error(subject/(storeA * storeB * storeC * storeD)), data=groceries)`. I guess this is not surprisingly, since even though modeled as interactions, there are actually no interactions between the four variables representing the repetition of measure. Regarding your proposal about Cross Validate: This seems to make sense.